# How to detect/inspect element in desktop application developed in Juce framework and C++ application?

Tags: c++, desktop-application, juce, appium-desktop, winappdriver

I am trying to automate desktop application which was developed by CPP and juce framework. I have tried with the tools such as 'UIAVerify', 'Inspect.exe', 'UISpy', but object or elements in that desktop application not able to identify, could any one help on this?

```
Using inspect or UIAVerify tools only main windows is displayed like below information:
```

How found:  Selected from tree...

```
Name:   "NEET."
ControlType:    UIA_WindowControlTypeId (0xC370)
LocalizedControlType:   "window"
BoundingRectangle:  {l:2332 t:248 r:3134 b:696}
IsEnabled:  true
IsOffscreen:    false
IsKeyboardFocusable:    true
HasKeyboardFocus:   false
AccessKey:  ""
ProcessId:  29416
RuntimeId:  [2A.40091C]
FrameworkId:    "Win32"
ClassName:  "JUCE_16f8e8b3839"
NativeWindowHandle: 0x40091C
```

Comment: Have you tried 'Accessibility Insights' ? This is what I use for inspection.

Comment: I have also tried with Accessibility Insights tools but it only shows me the Title bar(with icon,Title, minimize, maximize and close buttons) of the window. No other children are in the list. (Only main windows is displayed in inspect tools like other tools)